# Writing Xorg custom modeline for 1366x768 with nvidia driver

Tags: linux, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, debian-jessie, modeline

I've recently bought a Dell e1914h monitor 18.5" and supports 1366x768@60Hz display. The problem with proprietary nvidia driver is 1366x768 resolution is not supported by default due to some nvidia specific thing(resolution not dividable by 8). So, I get **1368x768** resolution with nvidia driver. I booted with nouveau on the live cd and copied the modelines to /etc/X11/xorg.conf and is working. Yes - 1366x768@60Hz mode with Nvidia is working after copying custom modeline from lmde live cd which uses nouveau driver module. But, what I want is, how to calculate the modeline when values like horizontal/vertical front porche, back porche etc are not known although I've some details about the monitor available:
http://cdn2.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/94125.pdf

What I wanted to achieve is a custom edid binary generated with 1366x768@60 supported for nvidia. What I have is the monitor specifications like horizontal, vertical sync range, Pixel Clock etc. I cannot find values like horizontal front porch etc to write the modeline manually. Can someone knowledgeable help? The problem with videogen, cvt, gtf etc are they all generated 1368x768 modeline instead of 1366x768. gtf output:

```
:~$ gtf 1366 768 60
# 1368x768 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 47.70 kHz; pclk: 85.86 MHz 
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"  85.86  1368 1440 1584 1800  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
```

I've seen a post [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1480033&p=9279575#post9279575), but does not explain all the horizontal and vertical values. I need to manually write a custom modeline which is confusing. Can someone shed some light on this?

These are the details of the monitor:

```
**Dell E1914H:**
```

- Horizontal resolution: 47.7Khz
- Vertical resolution: 59.8Hz
- Pixel Clock: 85.5Mhz
- Sync polarity: +/+ Scan range
- Horizontal: 30 kHz to 83 kHz (automatic) 30 kHz to 83 kHz (automatic)
- Vertical Maximum preset resolution: 56 Hz to 75 Hz (automatic)
- Maximum preset resolution: 1366 x 768 at 60 Hz
- Pixel pitch 0.30 (H) mm x 0.30 (V) mm
- Brightness (typical) 200 cd/m2
- Color gamut (typical) 83%
- Color depth 16.7 million colors
- Contrast ratio (typical) 600:1

**Supported resolutions:**
[image: Supported Resolution Dell E1914H]

This is the custom modeline I have copied from LMDE livecd:

```
    Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Dell"
    ModelName      "Dell E1914H"
    HorizSync      30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh    56.0 - 75.0
    DisplaySize    409.8  230.4
Modeline "1366x768"   85.50  1366 1436 1579 1792  768 771 774 798 +Hsync +Vsync
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection
```

Nvidia specific things like disabling edid on /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf:

```
    Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Nvidia 7300GT"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "UseEdidDpi" "FALSE"
    Option "ModeDebug" "true"
    Option "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "true"
    Option         "ModeValidation" "NoWidthAlignmentCheck, NoDFPNativeResolutionCheck"
#    Option "ModeValidation"    "AllowInterlacecModes, NoTotalSizeCheck,AllowNon60HzDFPModes,NoEdidMaxPClkCheck,NoVertRefreshCheck,NoHorizSyncCheck,NoDFPNativeResolutionCheck,NoVesaModes,NoEdidModes,NoXServerModes,NoPredefinedModes,NoMaxSizeCheck,NoVirtualSizeCheck,NoMaxPclkCheck,NoVertRefreshCheck"
    Option "UseEDID" "False"
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes   "1366x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

From Xorg.0.log:

```
    [     8.847] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   Validating Mode "1366x768":
[     8.847] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     1366 x 768 @ 60 Hz
[     8.847] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Mode Source: X Configuration file ModeLine
[     8.847] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):       Pixel Clock      : 85.50 MHz
[     8.847] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):       HRes, HSyncStart : 1366, 1436
[     8.847] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):       HSyncEnd, HTotal : 1579, 1792
[     8.847] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):       VRes, VSyncStart :  768,  771
[     8.847] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):       VSyncEnd, VTotal :  774,  798
[     8.847] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):       H/V Polarity     : +/+
[     8.847] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Mode is valid.
```

Present modelines hsyncstart hsyncend etc are not probably correct. According to XFree86 Wiki, I am missing hsyncstart hsyncend and vsyncstart vsyncend.

```
Modeline syntax: pclk hdisp hsyncstart hsyncend htotal vdisp vsyncstart vsyncend vtotal [flags]
 Flags (optional): +HSync, -HSync, +VSync, -VSync, Interlace, DoubleScan, CSync, +CSync, -CSync
```

I did calculate these values after looking [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1480033&p=9279575#post9279575):

```
"1366x768" 85.5 1366 hsyncstart hsyncend 1792 768 vsyncstart 795 vtotal +Hsync +Vsync
```

Answer (score 1):

The frequency and the 4 horizontal values scale with the horizontal resolution, while the 4 vertical values scale with the vertical resolution.

So you can just ask for double the resolution (1366*2 = 2736)

```
gtf 2736 768 60
```

And divide all the horizontal values, and the frequency, by two.